# JqGrid pager problem - Total pages and records does not display correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Issue: My jqGrid pager shows Page 1 of NaN instead of the correct number of pages.

Fiddler shows that I am getting the correct json from my WCF call:

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":2,"rows":[{JDEVendorNumber":99999999,
 "VendorName":"Super   Vendor","BillID":"99999999wwerer                      ",
 "CommunityName":"Post Abbey                              ",
 "PrimaryAcctNumber":"wwerer","CommunityID":"600402","RecordID":8}]}
```

My grid setup is as follows:

```
$invoiceGrid.jqGrid({
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        url: url,
        colNames: ['Vendor Name', 'CommunityName', 'Primary Acct Nbr', 'BillID'],
        colModel: [
                        { name: 'VendorName', index: 'VendorName', width: 203, align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'CommunityName', index: 'CommunityName', width: 215, align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'PrimaryAcctNumber', index: 'PrimaryAcctNumber', width: 260, align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'BillID', index: 'BillID', hidden: true }
                     ],
        rowNum: 50,
        gridview: true,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50],
        pager: $('#invoicepager'),
        sortname: 'PrimaryAcctNumber',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        rownumbers: false,
        hidegrid: false,
        repeatitems: false,
        recordtext: 'Bill(s) {0} - {1} ',
        cell: "",
        height: "auto",
        loadComplete: function(data) {
           //alert('total is ' + data.responseText);
            if ($invoiceGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') == 0) {
                NoRecordsFound();
            } else {
                SetSearchResultsInterface('bills');
            }

            EnableControl($search, true);
            Global.grdInitialized = true;
            $progressbar.hide();
        },
        jsonReader: {

            repeatitems: false,
            id: "RecordID"
        }
    }).navGrid('#invoicepager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
```

My data is displayed correctly but the pager shows NaN for total pages and total records. Any ideas? Thank you for your help

Comment: Try setting those names in your `jsonReader`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that correct format of `recordtext` should has 3 elements like

```
recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of {2}"
```

You use

```
recordtext: 'Bill(s) {0} - {1} '
```

You can use

```
recordtext: 'Bill(s) {0} - {1} of {2}'
```

instead. But I can not really reproduce your problem also in case of the usage of your original data (see http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/PagerProblem.htm which has no problems).
Moreover your JSON data should be fixed:

```
[{JDEVendorNumber"
```

should be fixed to

```
[{"JDEVendorNumber"
```

but probably it's come during posting the data only.

Comment: Still the same problem if I use 'Bill(s) {0} - {1} of {2}' ,it just displays Bill(s) NaN - NaN of NaN. My JSON response message is properly formatted as I can display the actual rows in the grid. It just the pager shows NaN for all the integer values it expects. Thanks

Comment: Oleg,the JSON data missing " was done by me when pasting the string during my posting.

Comment: You should search your problem in the part of code which you not posted here. Look at http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/PagerProblem.htm. This work without any problem.

Comment: By the way, it's not an error, but it seems to me that parameter `cell: ""` don't known by jqGrid.

Comment: @Oleg: +1 for your explanation with demo. Also I have a small query, if the jqgrid has no rows at some time, it shows `Page 1 of Nan` what is `Nan` here? Here I asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092924/on-0-row-in-jqgrid-how-can-we-replace-page-1-of-nan-to-something-else)

Answer (score 1):

Oleg, by looking at the sample code you sent me, I figured that for the pager to work correctly you need to include grid.formedit.js. In my page I had references only to grid.locale-en.js and jquery.jqGrid.min.js. Apparently that is not enough. I guess, lesson learned for me is to include all the .js libraries that are part of the jqGrid download. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Although it does not seem to be the problem here, the `loadonce` parameter may cause a similar issue (total pages always set to 1). It should be forced to `false`:

```
$myGrid.jqGrid({
        datatype: 'json',
        loadonce: false,
        ...
}
```

The `loadonce` parameter prevents the client from loading further data after the initial load. As a side effect, the client ignores `total` and `records` in the server's response, using only the amount of rows to populate the pager.

In my own code, `loadonce` must have been defaulted to `true`, because the pager worked as soon as I explicitly set it to `false`.