# On 0 row in jqgrid how can we replace Page 1 of NaN to something else?

Tags: jqgrid

if the jqgrid has no rows at some time, it shows `Page 1 of NaN` what is `Nan` here? can't we change it to something more appropriate like `Page 0 of 0` or something better?

[image]

my jqgrid code

```
var grid = jQuery("#list1");


                grid.jqGrid({

                  datastr : xml,
                  datatype: 'xmlstring',
                  colNames:['cfgId','Name', 'Host', 'Description','Product', 'Type', 'Last Updated Time','Last Updated By','',''],
                  colModel:[
                      {name:'cfgId',index:'cfgId', width:90, align:"left", hidden:true},
                      {name:'cfgName',index:'cfgName', width:90, align:"left", formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions:
                                                                                {
                                                                                    baseLinkUrl:'javascript:',
                                                                                    showAction: "goToViewAllPage('",
                                                                                    addParam: "');"

                                                                                }},
                      {name:'hostname',index:'hostname', width:90, align:"left"},
                      {name:'cfgDesc',index:'cfgDesc', width:90, align:"left"},
                      {name:'productId',index:'productId', width:60, align:"left"},
                      {name:'cfgType',index:'cfgType', width:60, align:"left"},
                      {name:'updateDate',index:'updateDate',sorttype:'Date', width:120, align:"left"},
                      {name:'emailAddress',index:'emailAddress', width:120, align:"left"},
                      {name:'absolutePath',index:'absolutePath', width:90, align:"left", hidden:true},
                      {name:'fileName',index:'fileName', width:90, align:"left", hidden:true},
                  ],
                  pager : '#gridpager',
                  rowNum:10,
                  rowList:[10,50,100],
                  scrollOffset:0,
                  height: 'auto',
                  emptyrecords: 'No configurations loaded',
                  autowidth:true,
                  viewrecords: true,
                  gridview: true,
                  multiselect: true,
                  xmlReader: {
                      root : "list",
                      row: "Response",
                      userdata: "userdata",
                      repeatitems: false
                  },
                  loadComplete: function () {
                        var count = grid.getGridParam();
                        var ts = grid[0];
                        if (ts.p.reccount === 0) {
                            grid.hide();
                            emptyMsgDiv.show();
                        } else {
                            grid.show();
                            emptyMsgDiv.hide();
                        }
                    },
                  onSelectRow: function(id,status){
                      var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id); 
                      configid = rowData['cfgId'];
                      configname=rowData['cfgName'];
                      configdesc=rowData['cfgDesc'];
                      configenv=rowData['cfgType'];
                      absolutepath=rowData['absolutePath'];

                      /*filename=rowData['fileName'];
                      updatedate=rowData['updateDate'];
                      absolutepath=rowData['absolutePath'];*/
                      updateproductid=rowData['productId'];


                      $('#cfgid').removeAttr('disabled');
                      document.getElementById("cfgid").value=configid;
                      document.getElementById("cfgname").value=configname;
                      document.getElementById("cfgdesc").value=configdesc;

                      var element = document.getElementById('cfgenv');
                      if(configenv=="Production")
                          element.value = "Production";
                      else if(configenv=="Development")
                          element.value="Development";
                      else
                          element.value="Test/QA";
                      rowChecked=1;
                      currentrow=id;
                      }


                });
                grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
                jQuery("#m1").click( function() {
                    var s;
                    s = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
                    alert(s);
                });
                var myGrid = $("#list1");
                $("#cb_"+myGrid[0].id).hide();
                // place div with empty message insde of bdiv
                emptyMsgDiv.insertAfter(grid.parent());

         }
```

My Xml

```
<Response>
<isSuccess>true</isSuccess>
<operation>viewall</operation>
<message>No configurations were found for this project</message>
</Response>
```

Comment: I suspect you're returning bad data. The jqGrid demos don't do this. Check the row count and page size you return.

Comment: @Craig: I'll post my response from server next thing tomorrow morning. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: Could you include `jsonReader` definition in the jqGrid and the JSON data returned from the server? The problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755396/jqgrid-pager-says-1-of-nan/3759439#3759439) is already fixed, but you have some very close problem.

Comment: @Oleg: Hi Oleg, I updated my question with jqGrid code and xml response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same problem which was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755396/jqgrid-pager-says-1-of-nan/3759439#3759439), but with XML data.

In [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.base.js#L1086) the variable `rn` will be declared, but it will be not assigned it any value. The first assignment of the value `rn = parseInt(ts.p.rowNum,10);` will be [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.base.js#L1088) inside of `if(gxml && gl)` which is `false` in your case. So [the statement](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.base.js#L1181)

```
ts.p.lastpage = Math.ceil(gl/ rn);
```

produce `NaN` value.

To fix the bug you can modify the line 1086 of the `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` of the jqGrid 4.1.2 from

```
var gl = gxml.length, j=0, grpdata={}, rn;
```

to

```
var gl = gxml.length, j=0, grpdata={}, rn = parseInt(ts.p.rowNum,10);
```

The line 1088 which contains the same assignment can be removed.

How you can see in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon9.htm) (compare with [your same code](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon9bug.htm) used original `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) the changes fix the problem.

Comment: Please look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357996/weird-behavior-of-jqgrid-row-selection) my multiselect is behaving in a weird manner

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: I have seen your question, but I have to do other things now. Later after I find the time I will read your question und try to help you.