# Jqgrid showing page 1 of 0 on empty

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a question, when the grid is empty why does it show `Page 1 of 0` can't it be `Page 1 of 1` or something more reasonable?

[image]

My code

```
var xml=client.responseText;
         var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml); 
         var $xml = $(xml);

         xml=xml.replace(/<productId>1/g, "<productId>"+productMap['1']);
         xml=xml.replace(/<productId>2/g, "<productId>"+productMap['2']);
         xml=xml.replace(/<productId>3/g, "<productId>"+productMap['3']);


            $('#configDiv').empty();
            $('#configDiv').html(  '<div id="configDetailsGrid" width="100%"><table id="list1" width="100%"></table><div id="gridpager"></div></div>');

            //var grid = jQuery("#list1");
            //var iconAlert;

            var getColumnIndexByName = function (grid, columnName) {
                var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i = 0, l = cm.length;
                for (; i < l; i += 1) {
                    if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
                        return i; // return the index
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            },
            grid = jQuery("#list1"),
            iconAlert = '<span class="ui-state-error" style="border:0"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span></span>';
            grid.jqGrid({

              datastr : xml,
              datatype: 'xmlstring',
              //datatype: 'clientside',
              colNames:['cfgId','Name', 'Host','Operating System', 'Description','Product', 'Type', 'Last Updated Time','Last Updated By','',''],
              colModel:[
                  {name:'cfgId',index:'cfgId', width:90, align:"left", hidden:true},
                  //{name:'updateDate',index:'updateDate', width:12, align:'center', /*formatter: oldConfigurationWarning*/ },
                  {name:'cfgName',index:'cfgName', width:70, align:"left", formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: {baseLinkUrl: '#'} },
                  {name:'hostname',index:'hostname', width:70, align:"left"},
                  {name:'osname',index:'osname', width:90, align:"left"},
                  {name:'cfgDesc',index:'cfgDesc', width:90, align:"left"},
                  {name:'productId',index:'productId', width:40, align:"left"},
                  {name:'cfgType',index:'cfgType', width:50, align:"left"},
                  {name:'updateDate',index:'updateDate',sorttype:'Date', width:120, align:"left"},
                  {name:'emailAddress',index:'emailAddress', width:120, align:"left"},
                  {name:'absolutePath',index:'absolutePath', width:90, align:"left", hidden:true},
                  {name:'fileName',index:'fileName', width:90, align:"left", hidden:true}
              ],
              pager : '#gridpager',
              rowNum:1000,
              rowList:[10,50,100],
              scrollOffset:0,
              height: 'auto',
              emptyrecords: 'No configurations loaded',
              autowidth:true,
              viewrecords: true,
              gridview: true,
              multiselect: true,
              xmlReader: {
                  root : "list",
                  row: "Response",
                  userdata: "userdata",
                  repeatitems: false
              },

              loadComplete: function () {
                    var count = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam');
                    var ts = grid[0];
                    if (ts.p.reccount === 0) {
                        grid.hide();
                        emptyMsgDiv.show();
                    } else {
                        grid.show();
                        emptyMsgDiv.hide();
                    }

                    //for showlink and icon alert having date difference more than 90 days
                    var iRow, row, trClasses, $cell,
                    icfgName = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'cfgName'),
                    iupdateDate = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'updateDate'),
                    mygrid = grid[0],
                    rows = mygrid.rows,
                    cRows = rows.length,
                    myLink = function (e) {
                        var $td = $(e.target).closest('td'),
                            text = $td.text(),
                            $tr = $td.closest('tr'),
                            rowid = $tr[0].id;
                            goToViewAllPage(rowid);
                    };
                for (iRow = 0; iRow < cRows; iRow += 1) {
                    row = rows[iRow]; // row.id is the rowid
                    trClasses = row.className.split(' ');
                    if ($.inArray('jqgrow', trClasses) > 0) {
                        // the row is a standard row (only if subGrid:true are used)
                        var cellvalue1,firstDate,secondDate;
                        $cell = $(row.cells[icfgName]);
                        cellvalue1=$(row.cells[iupdateDate]).text();
                        firstDate = new Date();
                        //console.info(cellvalue1+", "+cellvalue1.length);
                        //var cellvalue1="08-18-2011 11:49:01";
                        if(cellvalue1.length>25)
                        {
                            secondDate=new Date();
                            //secondDate = secondDate.substring(0, secondDate.length-3);

                            if(diffOf2Dates(firstDate,secondDate,true)>=expireCondition)
                            {
                                $cell.prepend(iconAlert);
                            }
                            $cell.click(myLink);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            secondDate = cellvalue1.substring(0, cellvalue1.length-6);
                            if(diffOf2Dates(firstDate,secondDate,false)>=expireCondition)
                            {
                                $cell.prepend(iconAlert);
                            }
                            $cell.click(myLink);
                        }
                    }
                }

                },
              onSelectRow: function(id,status){

                  }
            });
            grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});

            var myGrid = $("#list1");
            $("#cb_"+myGrid[0].id).hide();

            // place div with empty message insde of bdiv
            emptyMsgDiv.insertAfter(grid.parent());

            //$("#list1").setGridParam({rowNum:10});
            //$("#list1").trigger("reloadGrid");

            $("#list1").setGridParam({rowNum:10}).trigger("reloadGrid");
            $("#list1").sortGrid('updateDate', false, 'desc');
```

My Xmldata (when empty)

```
<Response>
<isSuccess>true</isSuccess>
<operation>viewall</operation>
<message>No configurations loaded</message>
</Response>
```

**Update**

I updated accordingly but no still no luck, I still get the same old `Page 1 of 0`

```
 xmlReader: {
                  /*root : "list",
                  row: "Response",*/
                  root:"Response",
                  row:"list",
                  userdata: "userdata",
                  repeatitems: false
              },
```

my **jquery.jqGrid.min.js** file changes

```
if(locdata) {
            ts.p.records = gl;
            //Change after 1 of 0 (Oleg)ts.p.lastpage = Math.ceil(gl/ rn);
            ts.p.lastpage = Math.max(ts.p.page,Math.ceil(gl/ rn)); //line no 1181
}
```

my response

```
<Response>
  <isSuccess>true</isSuccess>
  <operation>viewall</operation>
  <message>No configurations loaded</message>
</Response>
```

**Update, something usefull**

If we reload the grid it solves the problem too

```
jQuery("#list1").setGridParam({rowNum:10}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Comment: The result depends on the input data which you use and from the `datatype` which you use. Could you post test XML data which are in the `datastr`? If you would use `json` or `jsonstring` as the input you would be implement any behavior which you need.

Comment: @Oleg: input type is xml, its the same input from this [location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357996/weird-behavior-of-jqgrid-row-selection)

Comment: I remember the answer, but I don't understand why you use 'xml' instead of 'json'. jqGrid have very flexible possibilities for JSON data and relatively restricted for XML data. Moreover the size of XML data is larger as JSON and processing of XML data is slower on both sides. In case of your problem you can implement `page` and `total` properties from `jsonReader` [as function](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function) (method). So you can return **any** value based on any data. `xmlReader` has no such possibility.

Comment: @Oleg: am i doing anything wrong? or is it the pagination always displays `1 of 0`when grid is empty? Also this is an old project in which only for this grid i am using xml rest uses json, the response format in this case cannot be changed, is there any other way?

Comment: You should include in your question the XML data which you use as "empty" XML which display `1 of 0`.

Comment: @Oleg: I included my xml data when data grid is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see that the XML data corresponds to `xmlReader` which you use. Probably you should switch the values of `root` and `row` properties:

```
xmlReader: {
    root : "list",
    row: "Response",
    userdata: "userdata",
    repeatitems: false
}
```

Additionally the input XML data contain no `page`, `total` and `records` properties. In case of usage of any other `datatype` as `'xml'` or `'xmlstring'` you can define `page`, `total` and `records` as functions inside of `jsonReader`. The `xmlReader` parameter don't support it.

Currently you don't define `page`, `total` and `records` properties. So the default values are used: `page: "rows>page"`, `total: "rows>total"`, `records: "rows>records"`.

The bug which I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092924/on-0-row-in-jqgrid-how-can-we-replace-page-1-of-nan-to-something-else/7104817#7104817) and in [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/page-1-of-nan-in-case-of-length-of-xml-data-is-0/) is still not fixed in the code of jqGrid 4.2.0. So your current data will display "1 of NaN" before you apply the fix.

After all you can consider to change the line [1193](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/grid.base.js#L1193) of the jqGrid code

```
ts.p.lastpage = Math.ceil(gl/ rn);
```

to have other value in the `lastpage`.

**UPDATED**: I suggest that you modify the line `ts.p.lastpage = Math.ceil(gl/ rn);` of the jqGrid code to `ts.p.lastpage = Math.max(ts.p.page,Math.ceil(gl/ rn));`.

In the case if your input data will contain no `<page>` element or if it contains `<Response><page>1</page>...` you will see `1 of 1`. If your XML data will contain `<Response><page>0</page>...` you will see `0 of 0`.

Comment: I tried `ts.p.lastpage=10000;` just to test, but it still does not show me `10000` in `Page 1 of 0` also after i interchange `root : "Response",
                   row: "list",` part, but no luck

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: I suggest that you modify the line `ts.p.lastpage = Math.ceil(gl/ rn)` of jqGrid source code to `ts.p.lastpage = Math.max(ts.p.page,Math.ceil(gl/ rn))`.

Comment: I don't get it, where am i going wrong? 

`In the case if your input data will contain no <page> element or if it contains <Response><page>1</page>... you will see 1 of 1`

I did exactly what you said. I've updated my question

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: Look at the examples: [page 0 of 0](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/PageMethod0.htm), [page 1 of 1](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/PageMethod1.htm) where are different only the value inside of `<page>...</page>`

Comment: I guess i'll have to change my response to have `<page>1</page><total>1</total><records>0</records>` Thanks :)

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: You are welcome! I think in the next time I will post more changes in trirand forum about the subject which we discuss here.

Comment: Hi Oleg, long time, If I have `<list><Response><page>1</page><total>1</total><records>0</records></Response></list>` as my empty response in xml, and since i have defined `row: "Response",` it will not return 0 from `getGridParam("records")` and so it will not display `emptyrecords: 'No configurations loaded',` I changed my jqgrid lib line no 1193 to your specific line. Now it shows correct page numbers, but the message `No configurations loaded` is no longer coming, it shows an empty row.

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: The problem which you described can be solved only by debugging. One have to have JavaScript code which defines jqGrid, to use jquery.jqGrid.src.js, to have the corresponding input XML and go through the code of jqGrid in debugger. So just reading of your comment I can't answer on your question.

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: You are welcome! You see yourself, that some small changing of the format of input data can change the usage of `emptyrecords`. So without the exact tescase one can't answer on your question.

Comment: Hi again, Sorry to bother you on this qn again. I need help with this question I used your example [page 1 of 1](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/PageMethod1.htm) (even the response format) and it works, but will it be possible to also display `No Configuration loaded` inside the grid, kind of like the one screenshot shown in this question? It seems the `emptyrecords` is not functioning

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EmptyMsgInBody.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4127666/315935). Probably it's what you need.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. Even I was looking at [some answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1534386/707414) which had somewhat similar solution with my tweeks, but your's is better. :)

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: You are welcome! By the way if some answer was helpful you should not forget to vote up it. Voting is the most important criteria in searching and sorting. Low voted answers will be very difficult to find. So voting is mostly not the way to get somebody additional reputation points, the feature is mostly *to help other* to find helpful answers on the stackoverflow. You have right to vote up about 30 questions or answers **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). So please use your right more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any positive effect to Oleg's latest update and the use of max(), because in my use context, the code doesn't go through this part.
However, there is another instance of ts.p.lastpage = ... in the source code.

> ts.p.lastpage = lp === undefined? 1 : lp;

to be replaced with:

> ts.p.lastpage = lp === undefined || lp === 0 ? 1 : lp;

That worked for me.