# show Custom Message at Table area in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, plugins, jqgrid

How to show a Custom Message @ the table area of JQGrid if any error/rows=[];

As shown in below image:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you used screenshort of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EmptyMsgInBody.htm) which I created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4127666/315935). In case if you have only the picture without the source code I included the full references (URLs).

If you use current version of jqGrid (4.5.2) I would modify a little the old demo. You can use additionally the trick described [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17786646/315935). Depend of the options of jqGrid you could need to use either `jsonReader` or `localReader` or both to change undefined of `0` value of `page` to the string `"0"`.

The new version of the demo you can find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EmptyMsgInBody_.htm).